# How do I print the UserDefaults information Label ? Swift

Tags: swift, uilabel, nsuserdefaults, splash-screen, uiscenedelegate

application welcome on first startup hello on next startup.
I tried using Scene Delegate UserDefaults but I can only print in console because I don't know exactly.

**I want the SplashViewController GreetingLabel section to write hello on the first startup of the application and welcome on the next startup, how can I do this?**

two screen splash screen and main screen

Scene Delegate

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
        if launchedBefore  {
            print("Hello")
        } else {
            print("Welcome!")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
        }
    }
```

SplashController

```
class SplashViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var greetingLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "splashToMain", sender: nil)
        }
        
    }
    

}
```

Comment: UserDefaults is application-wide.  If you want to follow through this approach read/set it in the view controller, not in scene delegate.

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution as you said.